# Connection of Gog and Yavan/Greece

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, gentiles

I saw somewhere that "Gog" mentioned in the Torah is Greece. Does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: I asume it has something to do with the fact that both magog (which I believe includes gog) and yavan are descedents of yafet who is identified with both...

Comment: The Radak (?) cited here seems to imply they're separate entities, though he has them interacting: http://www.aharit.com/A-05.html fn 19.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is Gog mentioned in the Torah. There is however Magog in parshas Noach.

In Yechezkel 38 2 Rashi and Radak says Gog is king of Magog. Radak says Magog is from Yefes, Malbim also connects them to Yephes through Tuval mentioned there. Yefes is classically associated with Greece, Rabbi Kaplan brings some identifying Yefes with the Greek Iapetus.

(Rabbi Kaplan though does not being any opinions connecting Magog specifically to Greece.)

Comment: what does this have to do with gog?

Comment: @loewian If Magog is from Yefes = Greece, and Gog is king of Magog = Yefes = Greece, than Magog is (roughly) king (representative) of Greece.

Comment: @LN6595 Ioewian was commenting on the original post I put up which was admittedly confused. I got lost in the cross referencing and forgot your original question:/ es chatai ani azkir.

Answer (score 1):

This is a topic I am right now studying, as far as I know, Yavan son of Japhet is the precursor of Rome, just as in secular history the greeks is from where Italy came. Thus, is not associated with Gog uMagog but with Esau. Gog is associated with the grandson of Esau, amalek. The source is in Numbers 21:20:

> וַיַּרְא֙ אֶת־עֲמָלֵ֔ק וַיִּשָּׂ֥א מְשָׁל֖וֹ וַיֹּאמַ֑ר רֵאשִׁ֤ית גּוֹיִם֙ עֲמָלֵ֔ק וְאַחֲרִית֖וֹ עֲדֵ֥י אֹבֵֽד
> "He saw Amalek and, taking up his theme, he said:
> A leading nation is Amalek;
> But its fate is to perish forever." JPS1985
> (https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.24.20?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en)

I read the commentaries and there is kind of a small machloket if the phrase "resheyit goyim amalek veacharito odei obed" refers to that is the first in history of humankind or it is the one who leads the 69 remaining nations against Israel. In the previous translation of JPS1917 it is translated as "first of the nations". Overall the conclusion seems to be both, that is the first formal nation in humankind and also the leading of nations against Israel in the final war of Mashiach. The clearest explanation is seen in Pri Tzaddik Nasso 15:2, from where we understand that Numbers 24:20 and Ezekiel 38 is the leading nation of Amalek;

> ואחר כל זה יהיה עוד מלחמת גוג ומגוג על משיח בן יוסף כי גומ"ג הוא מזרע עמלק
> "...and after all of this still there will be the war of Gog uMagog upon Mashiach ben Yoseph, for Gog uMagog is from the seed of Amalek"
> https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Tzadik%2C_Nasso.15.2?vhe=Pri_Tzaddik,_Lublin,_1901&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

So, right now I am doing a clip from rabbi Daniel Glatstein /shlita/ where he explains what Rav Kanievsky ZT'L said about Gog uMagog and the clipped part starts talking about Yavan being a /shor/, an ox. Esau is associated with an ox or bull, correct me if they are not the same animal, I think that are very similar, same class. Link: https://youtu.be/PUpM8VcLScM?si=JEqTHRSaw4lm2K6k (timestamp 24:45)

Also a couple months ago rabbi Yitzchak Breitowitz /shlita/ said in a shiur that Yavan had a blessing, already when he had not yet assimilated within Esau. So there is something with these two, with Yavan, and with Magog. The first assimilates into Esau, and the latter into Esau's grandson amalek.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yisrael and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!