# What is the origin of the claim that they played games to hide Torah learning prior to Chanuka

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, chanuka, provenance, games-toys

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56033/what-did-%D7%A0-%D7%92-%D7%94-%D7%A9-stand-for-before-the-hanukkah-miracle) makes a very commonly heard claim: "Before the miracle of Hanukkah, when those who controlled the land severely restricted Torah study, Jewish children would gather to study Torah in secret, and brought dreidels with them so that, should they be discovered by the authorities, they could appear to be playing rather than studying."

What is the origin of this claim?

Comment: I just saw this in taamei haminhagim. Don't remember where the mekor is though

Comment: @Mefaresh, I took a quick scan through the Chanuka section and didn't see it, FWIW.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel Chanuka - page 306](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=302&hilite=) mentions this in the name of Otzar Kol Minhagei Yeshurin. Rabbi Genut at [din.org.il](http://www.din.org.il/2010/12/03/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A7-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9F/) also quotes Otzar Kol Minhagei Yeshurin and says it is mentioned in [Chapter 19:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2604&st=&pgnum=95) in the name of the Avodas Eved M'Lomza. [YUTorah.org](http://www.yutorah.org/_materials/Source_sheets-513377.pdf) also gives the Otzar Kol Minhagei Yeshurin as the source. This leads me to believe that there is no earlier source than the late 19th century.

Comment: When were these works written?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the Otzar Kol Minhagei is the first half of the 20th century. I'm not sure when his source is exactly from. If you see the link, he quotes the author of Avodas Eved and Tiferes Tvi as quoted by Rav Zivu. But I have no idea who Rav Zivu is or what exactly he quotes (oral history?). If [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/6327) is the relevant sefer, then I see another [sefer](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7501&st=&pgnum=4) by the same author with a Haskama From R. Avraham Chaim Naeh, so everything is early 20th century so far.

Comment: @Yishai Editing in such information would improve this answer IMO, or at least clarify its weaknesses.

Comment: @Yishai [Tiferes Tzvi](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/35951) & [Avodas Eved](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/6327) are the same author

Comment: @GershonGold, ah, for some reason I couldn't find the Tiferes Tzvi when I looked. Yeah, so that pretty clearly establishes who we are talking about. The only open question is who is Rav Zivu (Zivo?) and did he write anything on this?

Comment: @Yishai - Perhaps he is talking about [Rabbi Simcha Zeisel Ziv from Kelm](http://hebrewbooks.org/41658)?

Comment: If so, we can go back to the late 19th century (cc @DoubleAA).

Comment: @Yishai - However I am not certain that it is him

Comment: http://www.dinonline.org/2014/12/13/the-chanukah-dreidel-and-its-halachos/

Comment: @GershonGold, you should update your answer then, as there it puts the publication of Otzar Kol Minhagei Yeshurin at 1890, so late 19th century instead of early 20th.